# Border width based on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating diagonal top and bottom pieces to sections on a website.

I was wondering if there is a simple jquery solution to style the border width based on the screen size?  I can't use a set long size with overflow: hidden because the diagonal line isn't the correct angles.

The only way I can see to make the angles consistent is to have jquery set the border width based on the screen size.

```
.odd-section-top {
border-width: 0px 0 60px 2880px;
border-style: solid solid solid dashed;
border-color: transparent transparent #23264c transparent;
}

.odd-section-middle {
min-height: 600px;
padding: 50px 0;
background: #23264c;
}

.odd-section-bottom {
border-width: 0 2880px 60px 0;
border-style: solid dashed solid solid;
border-color: transparent #23264c transparent transparent;
}
```

Jquery would then generate a style that would read

```
.odd-section-top {
border-left-width:
}

.odd-section-bottom {
border-right-width:
}
```

And populate the numbers based on the screen size.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do everything within Javascript:

```
var borderWidth = $elem.css("border-left-width");
$(".odd-section-top").css("border-width", borderWidth);
```

You can adapt it to your desired logic.

Comment: This is what I tried. I'm still newer to javascript and jquery so maybe my synax closing is wrong (according to error console).

Answer (score 0):

Tried this but I know I messed up some of the syntax.  I'm still newer to javascript and jquery.  Is this on the right track?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
responsiveradio.initBorders = function () {

    var $window = $(window),
        $topOddBox = $('.odd-section-top'),
        $botOddBox = $('.odd-section-bottom'),
        $topEvenBox = $('.even-section-top'),
        $botEvenBox = $('.even-section-bottom'),
        ;

    function resetBorders() {
        var w = $window.width(),
        $topOddBox.css('border-left-width', w);
        $botOddBox.css('border-right-width', w);
        $topEvenBox.css('border-left-width', w);
        $botEvenBox.css('border-right-width', w);
    }  
});
</script>
```